# Could we add formatting to closed threads?

Tags: feature-request, formatting, user-interface

I would love it if the JSE would apply special formatting to closed threads.

Threads that belong to tags that I'm watching get a yellow hightlight.  I can immediately identify these in the list.

Closed threads, however, have the same formatting as regular threads.  This makes them visually harder to weed out and ignore.

**Suggestion:** Apply italics, and use a lighter gray color for the text of closed threads (in the main listing on the front page).  This would improve site usability by adding an immediate visual indicator that a thread is closed, in a way that is easier and quicker to see than the current markers like "[closed]" / "[duplicate]" appended to the end of the title.